# R - calculate column based on formula stored in other column

Tags: r, sas

My table contains data [rebate calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1T7A.png)

In R, how to add a new column "rebate" which has the value based on the calculation of the "formula" column?

The following code works but the results are wrong.

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  din_pin = c(12345678, 23456789, 2789),
  eff_price = c(10, 6, 0.6),
  qty = c(100, 100, 1000),
  list_price = c(12, 7, 0.85),
  form_price = c(0, 5.5, 0.65),
  formula = c("(eff_price - list_price)*qty", 
              "(form_price - list_price)*qty", 
              "(eff_price - list_price)*qty")
)

for (row in 1:nrow(test_df)){
  formula_text <- as.character(test_df[row, "formula"])
  print(formula_text)
  test_df$rebate[row] <- eval(parse(text = formula_text), test_df)
}
```

if I change the formula value to this:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  din_pin = c(12345678, 23456789, 2789),
  eff_price = c(10, 6, 0.6),
  qty = c(100, 100, 1000),
  list_price = c(12, 7, 0.85),
  form_price = c(0, 5.5, 0.65),
  formula = c("(test_df$eff_price[row] - test_df$list_price[row])*test_df$qty[row]", 
              "(test_df$form_price[row] - test_df$list_price[row])*test_df$qty[row]", 
              "(test_df$eff_price[row] - test_df$list_price[row])*test_df$qty[row]")
)
```

the results are correct.

However, I want the code to be general (independent from the data frame).

I accomplished the similar task in SAS like this:

```
data test;
    infile datalines dsd dlm = "," missover;

    input din_pin       :8.
          eff_price     :9.4
          qty           :8.
          list_price    :9.4
          former_price  :9.4
          formula       :$50.
    ;

datalines;
12345678, 10.0000, 100, 12.0000, 0.0000, (eff_price - list_price)*qty
23456789, 6.0000, 100, 7.0000, 5.5000, (former_price - list_price)*qty
2789, 0.60000, 1000, 0.850000, 0.6500, (eff_price - list_price)*qty
;
run;

data _null_;
    set test end=end;
    count+1;
    call symputx('rebate_formula'||left(count),compress(formula));
    if end then call symputx('max',count);
run;

%macro calculate_rebate;
    data rebate;
        set test;
        %do i = 1 %to &max;
            if _n_ = &i then do;
                rebate = &&rebate_formula&i;
            end;
        %end;
    run;
%mend calculate_rebate;

%calculate_rebate;

proc print data = rebate;
run;
```

I think in R it should be easier. I just can't get it right.

Comment: R centers on functional programming. Usually one does not save code commands in data structures but explicitly runs code by various needed logic which helps in debugging and workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DomPazz.

Here is the revised code:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  din_pin = c(12345678, 23456789, 2789),
  eff_price = c(10, 6, 0.6),
  qty = c(100, 100, 1000),
  list_price = c(12, 7, 0.85),
  form_price = c(0, 5.5, 0.65),
  formula = c("(eff_price - list_price)*qty", 
              "(form_price - list_price)*qty", 
              "(eff_price - list_price)*qty")
)

for (row in 1:nrow(test_df)){
  formula_text <- as.character(test_df[row, "formula"])
  print(formula_text)
  test_df$rebate[row] <- eval(parse(text = formula_text), test_df[row,])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the eval does not know what row you are evaluating.  Try changing it to:

```
test_df$rebate[row] <- eval(parse(text = formula_text), test_df[row,])
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please accept and up vote.